# markup trouble about a div and a hole in its border

Tags: html, css, markup

is it possible to have a `<div style="border:1px solid red">` element (with some content, doesnt matter what is it exactly), and some element outside this div, which has a `background:white` property, and overlaps this div for 1 pixel at least? so that the border of div will not be of ideal rectangle  form, but with a "hole"?
and, preferrably, it is done not using any absolute positioning. and it works in all major browsers..? please give me just some idea, or probably it won't work out at all

Comment: You can use negative margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative margin:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; background: blue;">Stuff
    <div style="background: white; margin-left: -1px;"> Other Stuff</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VzU8w/1/

And if the element is outside of the `border: red` element:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; background: yellow;">Stuff</div>
<div style="background: white; margin-top: -1px;">Other Stuff</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VzU8w/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use absolute positioning, use **float** and **margin**